# Подключение к postgresql из lapis

Tags: lua

Добрый день, решил поиграться с lapis - https://github.com/leafo/lapis, но приложение падает при попытке запроса к базе(PostgreSQL) с выводом:

```
2017/07/01 16:04:26 [error] 31284#0: *8 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: attempt to yield across C-call boundary stack traceback: coroutine 0:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/lapis/init.lua:15: in function 'serve'
        content_by_lua(nginx.conf.compiled:22):2: in function <content_by_lua(nginx.conf.compiled:22):1>, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Код вызывающий ошибку

```
local db = require("lapis.db")
local res = db.query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

config.lua

```
config({ "development", "production" }, {
    postgres = {
        host = "0.0.0.0",
        port = "5432",
        user = "wars_base",
        password = "12345",
        database = "wars_base"
    }
})
```

База работает, таблица создана, в таблице 1 запись.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ошибка в первой строке?

Comment: С чего Вы это взяли?

Comment: Я спрашиваю. В какой строке кода возникает ошибка. В первой? Ошибка не может возникнуть в "коде", она всегда возникает в какой-то определённой строке этого самого кода.

Comment: Ошибка возникает при вызове `db.query("SELECT * FROM users");`

Comment: Ответ: https://github.com/leafo/lapis/issues/556

Comment: Так напишите его тут как ответ, а не как комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: Выполнять запросы к БД возможно только в обработчиках запросов к серверу.

https://github.com/leafo/lapis/issues/556

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/178092)

Comment: @cheops мне кажется, что это вполне себе ответ. По ссылке ничего нового.